# Rails 4 - how to add a static page to a view folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called Article in my rails 4 app.

I want to add a static page called foldaway.html.erb to my views/articles folder.

I have added that view page, and updated my articles controller with:

```
def foldway
end
```

I have also tried to exclude foldaway from the set_article method:

```
before_action :set_article, except: [:foldway], only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
```

In my routes file I have added:

```
  get '/foldway' => 'articles#foldway'
```

When I save all this and try to test if the page renders, I get an error that says:

```
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=foldway
```

Why is it trying to set the article id when I have excepted it from the set_article method in my rails controller. I just want it to render a static page.

How do I add this to my file?

My complete article controller is:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, except: [:foldway], only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show ]
  layout "article"

  respond_to :html, :json
# GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = policy_scope(Article)
    # query = params[:query].presence || "*"
    # @articles = Article.search(query)
  end

  # def index
  #   if params[:query].present?
  #     @books = Book.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
  #   else
  #     @books = Book.all.page params[:page]
  #   end
  # end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show

  end

  def foldway
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.comments.build
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit

    authorize @article
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    # before_action :authenticate_user!
    # authorize @article
    @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    # before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    respond_to do |format|
    #   if @article.update(article_params)
    #     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
    #   else
    #     format.html { render :edit }
    #     format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    #   end
    # end
      if @article.update(article_params)
         format.html { redirect_to(@article) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status:      :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end



  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      authorize @article
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:body, :title, :image, :tag_list,
        comment_attributes: [:opinion])
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete controller code for Articles?

Comment: If you are using **only** then what is the need of **except** in **before_action** ?

Comment: Because it doesn't work with just only - so I added except to try to bolster it.

Comment: You could consider gems like [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) or other [static website generator](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation) to achieve your goal.

Comment: I just added high voltage gem, and then added this to my routes: get 'pages/foldway' => 'high_voltage/articles#foldway', id: 'foldaway'. It doesn't work. It's still looking for article_id

Comment: When I then make the route : get articles/foldway' => 'high_voltage/articles#foldway', id: 'foldaway', I get this error: uninitialized constant HighVoltage::ArticlesController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from your routes file.

I advise you tu put this inside your routes.rb file :

```
get 'articles/foldway' => 'articles#foldway', as: :foldway

match '/foldway', to: 'articles#foldway', via: :get
```

and for your articles controller you just have to put :

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
```

Comment: How can I link to it in the view? This doesnt work: <a class='btn btn-info btn-line'><%= link_to 'READ MORE', article_foldway_path %></a>

Comment: If you put the match like me, you can write your link_to like this : <% link_to 'READ MORE', foldway_path %>